# Does Angular send data to Google?

Tags: angular

If I use Angular for my website, will it send data to Google as I use it? If so, is there any way to prevent this? I don't feel I can say my website is safe and secure if it's sending information to Google without me knowing.

Comment: Not unless you implement Google Analytics, etc, however Angular CLI will send usage stats back unless you disable it: https://angular.io/analytics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news: no, and you can [check for yourself](https://github.com/angular/angular).

Comment: Google may not track users directly through the Angular code base, but what about JavaScript/CSS files hosted in Google's CDN? Also, what about other Google web tools like PageSpeed? It does appear through analysis of browser network traffic that Google is actively tracking end users (beyond even simply analyzing the CDN requests, which would not be visible to the user/developer).

Comment: I agree, but the question was specifically about whether Angular had telemetry, not about  node packages, external scripts, browser analytics, etcetera. I also agree with the close reason for the same reason you're bringing up.